# Does the Conexant CX06836 modem chipset support caller Id?

Tags: modem, usb-modem, caller-id

I have a USB modem based on the Conexant CX06836.11 chipset. I would like to use its caller Id function (if it is available). Does anybody know with certainty if this chipset supports the caller id function?
I found the chipset's datasheet [here](http://www.datasheetlib.com/datasheet/671372/cx06836_conexant-systems.html) but it doesn't mention the caller Id function. When I connect to it (via putty) and issue the AT command to show the caller information (AT +VCID=1), it responds with OK. But when I call the number, no caller Id data is shown in putty. It only shows RING, RING,... The caller id is usually found between the first and second RING.

Thanks for Your time.